# Simple 1 Page PHP Login Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

NOTE: Before we get started, YES I understand this is not the most secure type of login. I am comfortable using this. However if you can modify this to work with MySql I will use that instead, but I cannot seem to get this script to work anymore after I added the cookies to it. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass'])) {
  $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
  $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
  }
else {
 $user = $_POST['user'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}

if($user == "user" && $pass == "pass") {
  setcookie("user", $user, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
  setcookie("pass", $pass, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
  echo 'Logged In';
}
else {
  if(isset($_POST))
    {?>

        <form method="POST" action="test.php">
        <label for="user">User</label> <input type="text" name="user"></input><br/>
        <label for="pass">Pass</label> <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
        </form>
<?php}
}
?>
```

The content I am securing with this, is just basic PHP forms. Nothing that can be used to harm my site if someone did get into this. Just don't want everyone accidentally accessing it.

Comment: Have you considered using sessions?

Comment: I have, but never have so not too sure where to start. I've looked at tutorials. I'm only securing this one page and everything on it is going to be changeable by select box only so i'm not to worried about it's content.

Comment: Don't **ever** store your password in a cookie. Also, why are you logging the user in if they already have a cookie? Seems kind of silly don't you think? Usually Cookies = **Authenticated**....

Comment: Know any good tutorials on sessions Darren? I've looked at a few but they leave me with more questions than answers.

Comment: It's simple @JesseElser, throw `session_start()` at the top of your php script, then simply set the session with `$_SESSION['user'] = $user;...etc` and when you want to end your session (i.e, logout), you just need to use `session_destroy()`.

Comment: So I can basically use part of my same script but add $_SESSION to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly advise against you using this in any kind of production environment, but if it's what you want to use then that's fine too.

I'll be showing you how to implement sessions instead of cookies here.

The very first step: **Whenever** you use sessions, the very first thing you need to do on every script that uses those sessions is to start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

Now for session the session, that's simple. All you need to do is add an index to the `$_SESSION` superglobal:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

The trick though is not to force your user to login through the procedure you currently have. A session **means** the user is authenticated, so you **don't** want to force them to login again. What you want to do is add a check at the top of your file like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    die(header("Location: admin.php")); // user is logged in, send them to admin/user only page...
}
```

---

Which ends up leaving your "Login" script looking like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    die(header("Location: admin.php")); // user is logged in, send them to admin/user only page...
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($user == "user" && $pass == "pass") {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        die(header("Location: admin.php"));
    } else {
        // add some sort of error handling here because the user had invalid credentials.
    }
} else {
 ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label for="user">User</label> <input type="text" name="user"></input><br/>
        <label for="pass">Pass</label> <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Just tried this. After submitting the form it didn't attempt to go to admin.php and when i refreshed the page it showed the login form again.

Comment: The username and password matching @JesseElser ?

Comment: Yep changed them. It's probably a minor mistake on my end. I actually did find a session tutorial that I understood fairly well and implemented at https://krisnaordinary.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/creating-a-simple-login-logout-session-using-php/ I really appreciate your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  Not sure why this mattered but it worked for me.  (I changed the cookie duration too, but that wasn't part of the fix.)

```
<?php
 if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass'])) {
  $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
  $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
  }
else {
 $user = $_POST['user'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}

if($user == "user" && $pass == "pass") {
  setcookie("user", $user, time() + (1800), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
  setcookie("pass", $pass, time() + (1800), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
  echo 'Logged In';
}
else {
  if(isset($_POST))
    {?>

        <form method="POST" action="test.php">
        <label for="user">User</label> <input type="text" name="user"></input><br/>
        <label for="pass">Pass</label> <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
        </form>
<?php
}}
?>
```

I changed your:

```
<?php}
}
?>
```

to:

```
<?php
}}
?>
```

Comment: Hey just out of curiosity what was the fix? I appreciate this. I'm going to use this temporarily while I build on a $_SESSION script :)

Comment: I moved the closing bracket:

Comment: You had:
    <?php}
    }
    ?>
And I did:
    <?php
    }}
    ?>